# How to use placeholder element from Semantic-UI?

Tags: javascript, css, html, semantic-ui

I want to use the [Placeholder element](https://semantic-ui.com/elements/placeholder.html)

```
<div class="ui placeholder">
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

But I can't figure out if I have to replace manually the content on it or there's a function out-of-the-box.

I have read the documentation but I haven't found anything for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no function out-of-the-box - you'd have to manually replace the contents of the placeholder elements, removing the `placeholder` class as you go.

Comment: Thanks! That was what I ended up doing.